# Present simple / continuous clauses

Tags: clauses

Why doesn't the following text include a '-ing' clause? for example, "she saw him **winking** his eyes"(=she saw him. He was winking his eyes). When should I use a 'present simple' clause instead of a 'continuous' clause?

> "Why was I forgotten?" Mary said, stamping her foot. "Why does nobody
>   come?"
>
> The young man whose name was Barney looked at her very sadly. Mary
>   even thought she saw him **wink** his eyes as if to wink tears away.
>
> "Poor little kid!" he said. "There is nobody left to come."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"See" is a [verb of perception](http://www.englishgrammar.org/verbs-perception/), and these can be followed by a present participle, or (as above) a bare infinitive. There are sometimes slight changes in meaning.

"I saw him wink." Suggests a single event whereas "I saw him winking."
Suggests repetition.

In the above example, either could have been used, and the author's choice to use an infinitive is mostly a matter of style.